# p:autoComplete insert a new value to database

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I use in my project a `p:autoComplete` with `multiSelection = true` and `forceSelection = false`. I use it to add "tags" to my object.
This works indeed very good and is very useful.

Now I got a question and I hope it is possible to solve it.

Example

Tags stored in database: test, example

If I type test, or example, autocomplete makes a suggestion.

Now i would like to type:

primefaces

which is not found in db. Now I want to push this value from my autocomplete into the database.

How can I do that?

Regards
LStrike

Comment: Interesting. How do you want to do . Add button or event (Enter input from user). Basically you need a event to catch which in turn will execute a insert query into database.

Comment: The best thing would be an event, but I also could use a button, if implementation would be easier. ok, having a query, which pushes a value to my database is not the problem. I would like to know, how to get an unknown value from that autocomplete box.

Comment: Hmm unknown value wont come in autocomplete  which in turn your db query will give the no. of element returned as zero.

Comment: A solution could be to grab the value which is send to my autocomplete-method (eg. "public List<String> autocomplete(String suggest){....}"). But how do I determine, that the user has finished typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I made up a solution, which works fine for me.

Primefaces autocomplete:

```
<p:autoComplete id="mulitAutoSchlagWorte"
                            value="#{entityHandler.entity.tags}" 
                            completeMethod="#{entityListHandler.completeAreaWithCreation}" 
                            var="_tag"
                            itemLabel="#{_tag.value}"
                            itemValue="#{_tag}"
                            multiple="true"
                            size="300"
                            converter="#{entityConverter}">

                </p:autoComplete>
```

List Handler, which also creates a new Tag:

```
public List<Tag> completeAreaWithCreation(String query) {

    List<Tag> returnList = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery(Tag.NAMED_QUERY_GET_TAGS_BY_LIKE, Tag.class).setParameter("tag", query.toLowerCase().trim() + "%").getResultList();

    if(returnList.size() == 0){
        if(query.endsWith(" ")){
            entityHandler.create();
            entityHandler.getEntity().value(query.trim());
            entityHandler.save();
        }
        returnList = completeAreaWithCreation(query.trim());
    }

    return returnList;
}
```